# Using objects to depict other objects

Tags: terminology

I was wondering if there exists a term that describes the practice of using objects to depict other objects.

To give an example:

In the painting "The Librarian", Arcimboldo uses books to depict a person.
So the artist uses objects (books) to depict something entirely different (a person).

Thanks!

[image]

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about art historical terminology. Terminology questions are fine if they can clarify a creative process, but this seems to have nothing to do with creating things.

Comment: @Joachim I guess I don't see the difference between this terminology question and our other technique or style identification terminology questions. The example might be a historical piece, but it's not merely a history or appreciation trivia. If you want to learn about a technique, it's generally fundamental to learn what it's called, first.

Comment: @WebHead You're right. I think that my decision was informed by both Arcimboldo's painting and the lack of any indication of artistic usage or usefulness. Vote retracted. (Also, it's Dwight).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## Pareidolia

> Pareidolia is the tendency to interpret a vague stimulus as something known to the observer, such as seeing shapes in clouds, seeing faces in inanimate objects or abstract patterns, or hearing hidden messages in music.
>
> <sup>source: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pareidolia)</sup>

There are many examples on the internet beyond Arcimboldo, just look for *Pareidolia in art*.

[image]

<sub>*Women Forming A Skull By Salvador Dali*</sub>

Comment: I don't think this is Pareidolia as there is nothing vague about what Arcimboldo is doing. It is not interpretive or hidden. He is purposely constructing, in a sculptural manner (he was a Mannerist after all), the figures in the paintings using inanimate objects. His work is considered unique, and the closest thing I found to a name for them is "double-meaning" paintings.